# Unit testing for inner exceptions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am writing some unit tests using Visual Studio's integrated framework. I need to write some test cases which pass when a proper exception is thrown. The problem is that the exceptions i need to test for are inner exceptions nested in a more general one. Is there some easy solution or do I need to extend the whole functionality. I am currently using the [ExpectedException] attribute, but it wont do much good in such a situation.

I am also curious what happens when we use [ExpectedException] while we also have some Assert logic in the test itself. Are both the conditions evaluated(exception was thrown and the Assert statement turned out to be valid) or the test passes immediately after the correct exception is thrown?

Comment: Don't use `ExpectedException` attribute (test could pass because of some arrange phase thrown the same exception not the act phase); Use `Assert.Throws<YourException>`

Comment: There isn't a method 'Throws' in the VS's framework. For most of the cases I use custom exceptions so that should make the use of the attribute accurate enough.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your framework doesn't support custom throwing, you usually have two choices:

1. Implement it yourself
2. Change (or extend) framework

I'll start with second solution. Consider using [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions) library. It allows you to do something like this:

```
Action deleteUser = () => usersRepository.Delete(new User { Id = null });

deleteUser
    .ShouldThrow<UserNotFoundException>()
    .WithInnerException<ArgumentNullException>()
    .WithInnerMessage("User Id must have value");
```

You will still use Visual Studio testing framework, just that you'll have one extra library for, well - fluent assertions.

First choice on the other hand is a bit more work as it is usually the case with hand-rolled solutions:

```
try
{
    usersRepository.Delete(new User { Id = null });
    Assert.Fail("Deleting user with null id should throw");
}
catch (UserNotFoundException ue)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(ue.InnerException.Message, "User Id must have value");
}
```

You replace `ExpectedException` attribute with custom code asserting actual exception instance. Like I said, it is more work but does the trick.

Comment: Yeah, that should be it. I just wanted to avoid extending functionality or using external libraries but it seems this is the only possible solution at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

Not a total solution, but in NUnit, you can do this sort of thing:

```
 var ex = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => thing.ThatThrows());
 Assert.That(ex.InnerException, Is.TypeOf<BadException>() );
```

Maybe you can in your test framework?

Comment: Like I stated in the comment to the question, the VS's framework doesn't support a method Throws and as far as I know, the only possible solution for "catching" exceptions is by using the attribute. Maybe i should alter the code as to throw the detailed exceptions instead of the nested variation.

Answer (score 6):

this is an old question but i want to share my own implementation of `ExpectedInnerExceptionAttribute` with you guys. maybe useful for someone

```
public class ExpectedInnerExceptionAttribute : ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute
 {
   public ExpectedInnerExceptionAttribute(Type exceptionType)
   {
     this.ExceptionType = exceptionType;
   }

   public Type ExceptionType { get; private set; }

   protected override void Verify(Exception ex)
   {
     if (ex != null && ex.InnerException != null
           && ex.InnerException.GetType() == this.ExceptionType)
      {
         return;
      }

       throw ex;
    }
}
```

You could also extend it to check exception message etc. you just need to add Your own logic in Verify method.

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing i currently use [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions). Since i learned it i never wanted to assert stuff in any other way.

For asserting exceptions look at this bit of the [documentation](http://fluentassertions.com/documentation.html#exceptions)

In particular this part

```
Action act = () => subject.Foo2("Hello");

act.ShouldThrow<InvalidOperationException>()
     .WithInnerException<ArgumentException>()
     .WithInnerMessage("whatever")
```

Answer (score 2):

[FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions) is really helpful.

and I achieved my solution using it as given below. This is checking my custom exception `ProcessFailureException` from `AggregateException`

```
Func<Task> func = async () => await item.ProcessAsync(context, message);
func.Should().Throw<AggregateException>().WithInnerException<ProcessFailureException>();
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use `GetAwaiter()` and `GetResult()` to check for inner exception:

```
Assert.Throws<InnerException>(() => thing.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

e.g.

```
Assert.Throws<CommunicationException>(() => thing.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```