# System exception is hidden by Autofac exception

Tags: c#, exception, nunit, autofac

I have an application where I throw exceptions in constructor of one class.
I have unit and integration tests written in nUnit and I check if this exception is thrown when I want, like this:

```
Assert.That(() => _fileOperationsModel.OpenFile("abc"), Throws.Exception.TypeOf<MissingFieldException>());
```

And it worked great until I have started to use Autofac. I need to create this class which throws an exception using autofac, so when constructor is called and my exception is thrown, there is no `MissingFieldException` anymore, but `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException`.

And in that excepetion's details, there are 4 inner exceptions. 3 of them are also `DependencyResolutionException` and the last of them is my `MissingFieldException`.

I was trying to test it like this:

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException>(() => _fileOperationsModel.OpenFile("abc"));
Assert.That(ex.InnerException, Is.TypeOf<MissingFieldException>());
```

but it doesn't work coz `InnerException` is only one and it is also `DependencyResolutionException`.

Do you have any idea how I can handle this exceptions and how I can test it? I am new in Autofac and I was trying to find something about that but with no result.

EDIT:
I know I can do that like this

```
  var ex = Assert.Throws<Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException>(() => _fileOperationsModel.OpenFile("abc"));
  Assert.That(ex.InnerException, Is.TypeOf<DependencyResolutionException>());
  Assert.That(ex.InnerException.InnerException, Is.TypeOf<DependencyResolutionException>());
  Assert.That(ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException, Is.TypeOf<DependencyResolutionException>());
  Assert.That(ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException, Is.TypeOf<MissingFieldException>());
```

but maybe there is some better and not so awful solution?

Comment: How do you know that there are 4 inner exceptions, while there is only one `InnerException`? Usually, when there are more Exceptions, either an `AggregateException` is used, or the inner exception itself has an inner expection again (like `ex.InnerException.InnerException`). Probably you can (with a debugger) find out the exact nesting structure of the exceptions.

Comment: In except details there is: Inner Exception 1: DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument, System.String)' on type 'OpenedReportFileBasic'.

Inner Exception 2: DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating _00_DataEngine.Entities.TestModule.ReportTestModuleBasic.

Inner Exception 3: DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Xml.Linq.XElement)' on type 'ReportTestModuleBasic'.

Inner Exception 4:MissingFieldException: ...

Comment: ok, I see what you mean. I have edited my question, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151897/unit-testing-for-inner-exceptions) can give you some inspiration.

Otherwise, you can try writing your own [constraint matcher](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Constraints) based on [the default exception matcher](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/801368f75e10debac29475ed63a78cabebb8af6a/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/ExceptionTypeConstraint.cs),
however in line 50 iterating over the inner exceptions.

If both are not an option, you could resort to your own proposed solution. I do not think deep nested inner exception verification is implemented in NUnit at this moment. Moreover, I think you can do without verifying the intermediate `DependencyResolutionExceptions`.